# Как научить программу считывать количество объектов?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

Изображение будет передаваться с квадрокоптера/дрона, называйте как хотите))
Нужно научить программу считывать количество людей в парке.
Я не кодер. Подскажите, такое возможно реализовать?
Ещё один вопрос, может быть кто знает. Вот квадрокоптер снимает на камеру сверху. Можно ли как-то сделать так чтобы это видео передавалось на сайт онлайн? Ну и на пульт управления тоже, конечно

Comment: "Я не кодер" - интересное начало, учитывая что для реализации вашего проекта КОДЕР - должен обладать знаниями в области машинного обучения, и нейронных сетей. Мало того этого недостаточно , так как вам нужен живой стрим - трансляция по каналам связи  - думаю во всём сообществе найдётся только несколько человек которые смогут это реализовать. Горькая правда в том, что не один не возьмётся за такую работу.

Comment: @DigitalCore, ну крутым ученым тут быть не обязательно,  с учётом количества готовых библиотек, где реализовано всё самое трудозатратное. А передавать не обязательно по GMSC. Если коптер уже передаёт на пульт изображение, можно считывать изображение с пульта и передавать на сайт уже любым привычным способом. Только чтобы это изображение прочитать, скорее всего понадобится разработчик, работающий с железом и драйверами, что конечно дороговато. (Можно ещё со смартфона камерой в перископ транслировать изображение пульта, ага)

Comment: @AlexanderGrushko ну ваш ответ я уже видел ниже, на самом деле нужна об ученая нейронная сеть, по распознаванию образов лиц. Из стандартных бесплатных библиотек с этим справится AfogeNet, в реальности для промышленных целей или трансляции канала, нужна своя сеть, и обучение под свои цели. 
Конечно можно пойти вашим путём , у Nvidia спи**** драйверы, у LeadeTools сеть, и тд. (трансляция со смарта вообще убила на повал).

Comment: В общем, автор, если не устраивает версия с перископом и фрилансерами, считающими количество людей на видео, готовьте пару десятков миллионов)

Comment: P/S на картплоттер я получаю данные с 49 камер размещённых на разной глубине, матрица преобразовывает данные в 3D объекты, с наложением цвета с транслируемого видео,

Comment: Ого. Звучит круто

Comment: @AlexanderGrushko Да, всё верно, я не разработчик. Для этой миссии я бы хотел нанять тех спец, видимо на фрилансе. Спасибо за идеи с перископом. Не вариант конечно, но всё же что-то))

Comment: @DigitalCore про Open CV что-нибудь скажете? Пусть коптер не будет передавать изображение на пульт. Ближайший аналог - трансляция футобольных матчей. Как-то же они передают картинку на экраны, ТВ и т.д.

Comment: Open CV способна распознавать довольно сложные объекты, было время я даже распознавал reCapcha от google при помощи этой библиотеки.  Касательно лиц не уверен, что данная библиотека будет работать корректно, и с нужной производительностью.

Comment: Digital Core Так как квадрокоптер будет снимать сверху, все люди будут выглядеть как маленькие квадратные объекты. Это сложно?
Лица не нужно распознавать. Высота около 300 метров

Answer (score 1):

Да, всё это можно сделать, это уже не научная фантастика. Вы можете поискать исполнителя. С распознаванием образов, скорее всего, будет дорого